# How to validate if user is signed in successfully through Gmail account login using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to automate Gmail account login with selenium webdriver, and I need the to check if account signed in successfully and give me the result.

How exactly I can do it?

```
y = input("input email ID: ")
x = input("input your password: ")            
browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/')
browser.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)    
User_Id = browser.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
User_Id.send_keys(y)
Next_Button = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierNext').click()
time.sleep(3)
password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys(x)
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can help you with where you're getting stuck.

Comment: You need to apply to assert after clicking on the login button and you can verify it in multiple ways like you can check the `email` is right through which you logged in or just assert the landing page title etc.

Comment: @MuhammadFarooq thanks for your comment, but i don't know what to search for with assert, or how to check the email is right.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal approach to validate if you have signed in successfully within your account will be to verify the visibility of a ***visible*** element.

Once you login through [Gmail account login](https://accounts.google.com/) you can verify the visibility of the either of the following elements inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Verifying the *Inbox* link:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@aria-label, 'Inbox') and contains(., 'Inbox')]")))
  ```
- Verifying the *Primary* tab link:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Primary']")))
  ```